# $((p\to q) \land (q \to p)) \to (p \leftrightarrow q)$ is tautology

Tags: logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

$((p\to q) \land (q \to p)) \to (p \leftrightarrow q)$ is tautology

I prove this by using proof by contradiction:

So I defined A = [(p $\implies$ q) $\land$ (q $\implies$ p)] and B = (p $\iff$ q) , and that will be A $\implies$ B. For this to happen A needs to be T and B needs to be F.

Therefore,  I went with my cases:

Case I: If p is T and q is F; A = F and B is F $\therefore$ A $\implies$ B is T

Case II: If p is F and q is T; A = F and B is F $\therefore$ A $\implies$ B is T

Case III: If p and q are the same; A = F (If p and q are both F) and B = T $\therefore$ A $\implies$ B is T;  or  A = T (If p and q are both T) and B = T  $\therefore$ A $\implies$ B is T.

By the proof of contradiction this is invalid therefore is tautology.

Then I got curious and tried to prove. this by using this rules only and failed completely, how can this be done by using this rules?:

[image]

Comment: In table 8 this is essentially given as a rule??

Comment: What do you mean by $p\iff q$ if not the left hand of your implication?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch, yes is given as a rule

Comment: @lulu what you mean?

Comment: I mean, what you wrote looks like a definition, not a theorem.

Comment: yes, I just want to know how can you condense it to get true value.

Comment: @EM4 I showed how you can use the rules to show it is equivalent to a tautology in my Answer below.

Comment: @Bram28 , I solved it I got it below as well :) and your answer is correct as well.

Comment: @EM4 Sorry, but that last step you did in your answer is not correct .... $(p \land q) \lor (\neg p \land \neg q)$ isequivalent to $p \leftrightarrow q$, which is not a tautology ....

Comment: yes! mines was all wrong hhahahaa. I believe your answer is correct.

Answer (score 3):

$$((p \to q) \land (q \to p)) \to (p \leftrightarrow q) \overset{Equivalence \ \text{(this is one of the rules from Table 8)}}{\equiv}$$

$$(p \leftrightarrow q)\to (p \leftrightarrow q) \overset{Implication \ \text{( this is one of the rules from Table 7)}}{\equiv}$$

$$\neg ( p \leftrightarrow q) \lor (p \leftrightarrow q) \overset{Commutation}{\equiv}$$

$$(p \leftrightarrow q)\lor \neg (p \leftrightarrow q)\overset{Complement \ \text{(one of the Negation Laws)}}{\equiv}$$

$$\top$$

Comment: so you convert the LHS to (p $\iff$ q) 

I breaking it down and going from there...I will show you. If I can make a chat on this.

Answer (score 2):

You can employ the equivalence from table 8, rule 1 to transform it into a tautology with the addition of meta-logical laws:

$\begin{align}
& \quad \ p \leftrightarrow q \equiv (p \to q) \land (q \to p) \quad & \text{(table 8 rule 1)} \\
& \rightsquigarrow p \leftrightarrow q \vDash (p \to q) \land (q \to p) \ \text{ and }\ (p \to q) \land (q \to p) \vDash (p \leftrightarrow q) \quad & \text{(def. } \equiv \text{)}\\
& \rightsquigarrow (p \to q) \land (q \to p) \vDash (p \leftrightarrow q) \quad & \text{(simplification)}\\
& \rightsquigarrow\ \! \vDash ((p \to q) \land (q \to p)) \to (p \leftrightarrow q) \quad & \text{(import-export theorem)}
\end{align}$

where "$\vDash$" means logical consequence/tautologicity.

Comment: how does this say this tautology

are you making both sides to be same?

Comment: The last line says that the implication is a tautology because the second-to-last linet says that $(→)∧(→)$ logically implies $↔$ because the equivalence rule from your table says that $↔$ and $(→)∧(→)$ are logically equivalent. What do you mean by "making both sides to be the same"?

Comment: I meant to say you changed (→) ∧ (→) for (↔) 

so it will be (↔) → (↔) 

but can you go further like Table 7 rule 1 and then use Negation Law like how @Bram28 did?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. I didn't change the first formula for the second, and there is no need to go further: The last line already is exactly what you want to prove.

Comment: Bram28 took a different approach: They started with the formula whose tautologically you want to prove and simplified it to $T$ by a chain of equivalences. In my answer, I started out with an already established fact, and the following lines have already incorporated that the formula hat follows is tautological, so no need to simpilfy any further.

Comment: I get what you did now, you used the definition of Table 8 Rule 1 and its logical equivalence to the other side and therefore is tautology.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111317/discussion-between-em4-and-lemontree).

Answer (score 2):

[image], [image]

What you did, by cases (there are four cases, two of which you covered in your Case III), is essentially describe the results of the truth table for the the truth value of each side of the implication in the title.

By your rules, we have $$(p\leftrightarrow q) \equiv ((p \to q) \land (q\to p)$$ which means, $$((p\to q) \land (q\to p))\equiv (p \leftrightarrow q).$$

And this means $$[((p \to q) \land (q \to p)) \rightarrow (p\leftrightarrow q)] \land [(p\leftrightarrow q) \to ((p \to q) \land (q \to p))].$$

Comment: I don't follow [((→)∧(→))→(↔)]∧[(↔)→((→)∧(→))] how did this became that? 

so its pointless to use the rules to condense it to find True value and my proof is correctly done?

Comment: Yes, you did all the work you need to do.